# How to Get the text from an element through Selenium and C#

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

How can i Get the 2.22 Number From this Codes?

```
<div class="crash-row crash-0d54ae895d62d03cfb4bdcb502109630">
    <div class="col bold h-col-1 c-green">2.22</div>
    <div class="col h-col-2">-</div>
    <div class="col h-col-3">-</div>
    <div class="col h-col-4">-</div>
    <div class="col h-col-5">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="show-code">0d54ae895d62d03cfb4bdcb502109630</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col h-col-6">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="show-code">8d76a8fa2b7613de95a7e13852055c77d013f441952a231c47ca0872bcdd64df</a>
    </div>
        <div class="clear">
    </div>
</div>
```

I had Tried This Code But it Does Not worked!
Note: The XPATH that I given is For `<div class="col bold h-col-1 c-green">2.22</div>` tag!

```
Console.Write(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]/div[5]/div[2]/div[5]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]")).Text);
```

Comment: Try CSS-selector `.crash-row > .c-green`. Also share more details about *"But it Does Not worked!"*

Answer (score 1):

You can first try to use relative xpath to find element as 
 `//div[contains(@class, 'h-col-1')]`

Then try to get the value using

1. Text  *(element.Text)*
2. Get Attribute  *(element.GetAttribute("value"))*

Answer (score 0):

To extract the text **2.22**, as the element is a dynamic element, you may use *WebDriverwait* with *element to be visible* and you can use either of the following solution:

- *CssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("div.crash-row > div.c-green"))).GetAttribute("innerHTML");
  ```
- *XPath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'crash-row')]/div[contains(@class, 'c-green')]"))).GetAttribute("innerHTML");
  ```